# Rationale behind hiding originating IP address in emails?

Tags: privacy, ip, smtp

Gmail has been hiding originating IP addresses for quite some time now. Hotmail and Yahoo have started doing this too.  Apart from obvious privacy implications of revealing the sender's IP address, is there another security aspect of hiding (and in many cases, hashing the originating IP address)?

Answer (score 2):

Hiding the originating IP can also help protect against attackers / phishing attackers that gain knowledge of the internal network of companies by getting the ip's of employees from the 'auto' mail replies.

But I believe the main reasoning is privacy.

Comment: ip's of employees from the 'auto' mail replies - I believe these are generated server side (at least for Exchange)

Comment: it depends on the client and settings. and on what type of auto reply it is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, privacy.

If the mail server is internet (or "cloud") based, hiding the IP address by not adding the `X-Originating-IP` header can prevent information leakage of the sender's public IP address.

If the mail server is LAN based, then the server with the last hop before WAN should also remove any `Received` headers containing private IPs to prevent the internal IP address of the user from being leaked. The public IP address may still be leaked and if the server shares the same outbound route as other traffic originating from the LAN this may be a concern.

If the user is sending the email from a small office or from home, then the public IP in the first case could be used to track them (e.g. source IP of requests in web logs), so removing this data (or not adding it in the first place) is a great step in protecting users' privacy.